# how to get to settings of adobe flash player?

Tags: flash

Adobe Flash Player is by default e.g. set to - always with access on webcam and microphone.

How do I get to settings of adobe flash player e.g. in chrome and in firefox for to
adjust privacy ?!

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager02.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run "Adobe Flash Player" in your Software List and your Settings will pop up to be changed.

Alternatively you can run flash-player-properties in terminal.

Another way is to open a website with flash Content (i.e. youtube) and right-click on the flash element and choose "Global Settings" to open the flash settings.

Have Fun!